# PortType(interface Name) is not used at runtime during SOAP call?

Tags: java, .net, wcf, soap

I would like know about PortType(Interface name) is used to validate at server side during SOAP client call. in other words, Only soapAction, headers and request should match at the server side, other than this PortType(Interface name) which is present in the existing WSDL will be not consider during run time. Any one please clarify about my assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know the name of portType and how to change it?

I'm not sure what you mean. Please refer to PortType Class first:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.description.porttype?view=netframework-1.1

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jiayao, consider I have WSDL imported long back and recently portType has been changed in server version, still call I succeeded without any exception. my question is here whether portType is considered for making call to server or not?

Comment: I think the porttype changed but the successful call means it has nothing to do with it